# Unit of Camera2 LENS_FOCUS_DISTANCE

Tags: android, android-camera2

I find this documentation unclear
https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest#lens_focus_distance

**What is the unit of the lens focus distance ? m (meter), cm, inch**

If I set as below

```
previewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.LENS_FOCUS_DISTANCE,0.20f);
```

then the lens focus distance is in cm, inch ?

Introduction to [lens focus distance](https://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/basics/19/04.htm)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As referenced in the docs, the units are dependent on the value of the [FOCUS_DISTANCE_CALIBRATION](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics#LENS_INFO_FOCUS_DISTANCE_CALIBRATION:android.hardware.camera2.CameraCharacteristics.Key) field.  If that field is set to APPROXIMATE or CALIBRATED, the units are [diopters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dioptre), which are 1/meters.  So 0.5 diopters is a focus distance of 2 meters, and 4 diopters is a focus distance of 0.25 meters.  This makes representing infinity focus distance simple (it's 0 diopters), among other benefits for optical systems.

If the field is set to UNCALIBRATED, the camera system cannot do repeatable focusing, so there's no reasonably accurate physical value to the settings, besides 0 being infinity and [MINIMUM_FOCUS_DISTANCE](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics#lens_info_minimum_focus_distance) being the closest focus distance one can set.  It'll probably be roughly in diopters still, but not in a way that's very accurate at all.

Comment: Thanks ! I hoped the official documentation was as clear as your answer.